# Is there a web where I can beautify arrays of php?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a website where I can beautify arrays ?

Something like this one, but for PHP:
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

I want to beautify this array so I can see the information clearly.

```
Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 524 [idEmpleado] => 2123 [nroDocumento] => 10782295 [dia] => 1 [idHorario] => 2 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 525 [idEmpleado] => 2123 [nroDocumento] => 10782295 [dia] => 2 [idHorario] => 2 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 526 [idEmpleado] => 2123 [nroDocumento] => 10782295 [dia] => 3 [idHorario] => 1 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 527 [idEmpleado] => 2123 [nroDocumento] => 10782295 [dia] => 4 [idHorario] => 2 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 528 [idEmpleado] => 2123 [nroDocumento] => 10782295 [dia] => 5 [idHorario] => 2 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 529 [idEmpleado] => 2123 [nroDocumento] => 10782295 [dia] => 6 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 530 [idEmpleado] => 2123 [nroDocumento] => 10782295 [dia] => 7 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) ) Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 531 [idEmpleado] => 2857 [nroDocumento] => 41398017 [dia] => 1 [idHorario] => AASDF [idUsuario] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 532 [idEmpleado] => 2857 [nroDocumento] => 41398017 [dia] => 2 [idHorario] => sdf [idUsuario] => 3 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 533 [idEmpleado] => 2857 [nroDocumento] => 41398017 [dia] => 3 [idHorario] => as [idUsuario] => 3 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 534 [idEmpleado] => 2857 [nroDocumento] => 41398017 [dia] => 4 [idHorario] => ffdf [idUsuario] => 3 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 535 [idEmpleado] => 2857 [nroDocumento] => 41398017 [dia] => 5 [idHorario] => tres [idUsuario] => 3 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 536 [idEmpleado] => 2857 [nroDocumento] => 41398017 [dia] => 6 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 537 [idEmpleado] => 2857 [nroDocumento] => 41398017 [dia] => 7 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) ) Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 538 [idEmpleado] => 23 [nroDocumento] => 24242 [dia] => 1 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 539 [idEmpleado] => 23 [nroDocumento] => 24242 [dia] => 2 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 540 [idEmpleado] => 23 [nroDocumento] => 24242 [dia] => 3 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 541 [idEmpleado] => 23 [nroDocumento] => 24242 [dia] => 4 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 542 [idEmpleado] => 23 [nroDocumento] => 24242 [dia] => 5 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 543 [idEmpleado] => 23 [nroDocumento] => 24242 [dia] => 6 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 544 [idEmpleado] => 23 [nroDocumento] => 24242 [dia] => 7 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) ) Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 545 [idEmpleado] => asdf [nroDocumento] => 23 [dia] => 1 [idHorario] => 2 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 546 [idEmpleado] => asdf [nroDocumento] => 23 [dia] => 2 [idHorario] => 2 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 547 [idEmpleado] => asdf [nroDocumento] => 23 [dia] => 3 [idHorario] => 3 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 548 [idEmpleado] => asdf [nroDocumento] => 23 [dia] => 4 [idHorario] => 4 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 549 [idEmpleado] => asdf [nroDocumento] => 23 [dia] => 5 [idHorario] => 5 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 550 [idEmpleado] => asdf [nroDocumento] => 23 [dia] => 6 [idHorario] => 6 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 551 [idEmpleado] => asdf [nroDocumento] => 23 [dia] => 7 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) ) Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 552 [idEmpleado] => sadf [nroDocumento] => asfd [dia] => 1 [idHorario] => 67 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 553 [idEmpleado] => sadf [nroDocumento] => asfd [dia] => 2 [idHorario] => 6 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 554 [idEmpleado] => sadf [nroDocumento] => asfd [dia] => 3 [idHorario] => 8 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 555 [idEmpleado] => sadf [nroDocumento] => asfd [dia] => 4 [idHorario] => 9 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 556 [idEmpleado] => sadf [nroDocumento] => asfd [dia] => 5 [idHorario] => 0 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 557 [idEmpleado] => sadf [nroDocumento] => asfd [dia] => 6 [idHorario] => 8 [idUsuario] => 3 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [idTempHorario] => 558 [idEmpleado] => sadf [nroDocumento] => asfd [dia] => 7 [idHorario] => 6 [idUsuario] => 3 ) )
```

Comment: `echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it yourself:

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r( $your_array ); ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can output an well formatted array in a php page by adding the pre tag between your array. Example as below

```
$myArray = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myArray);
echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: This message was after me and it's like copy ! I suggest that you judge for yourself. @DigitalFrequency

Comment: @MohammadrezaYektamaram Yes, you are right. Better late than never I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pre tag to output the php array in well formatted.

look here >> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `print_r` or `json_encode` as given below,
using `print_r()` function

```php
print_r($array);
```

using `json_encode` with JSON_PRETTY_PRINT flag

```php
echo json_encode($array , JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```